# No webpack in Angular-CLI ng new

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I created an app using Angular CLI using:

`ng new my-app`

There is no Webpack configured by default and in Chrome dev tools the .ts files are not showing/mapped so I can only debug the transpiled JS.

**Why is Webpack not in there by default, has Angular got its own alternative?**

**Is this the reason my .ts files are not mapped properly?**

EDIT - after reading @torazaburo 's comment - here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Also to add my coworker went through the same steps as me, I assume, and they have the .ts files served by webpack in chrome dev tools

Comment: angular-cli hides webpack so you don't have to worry about it. Make sure you have sourcemap options turned on in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I do have it turned on, will update with config, thanks

Comment: what version of cli are you using?

Comment: My Angular CLI version is 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Installed latest stable Chrome to fix it.

I was using Chromium Version 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).
I noticed my colleagues version of Chromium was higher, but since I'm having a bug with Ubuntu software center - I just installed the latest Chrome. This solved my issue.